# Rapid polymerization inside cells

Tags: cell-biology, polymerase

I am interested in (rapid) polymerization or (rapid) long mollecule synthesishappening in the intracellular space.

Clearly protein synthesis or DNA/RNA synthesis are examples of elongation of molecules, but these are relatively slow.

I wonder if someone can suggest examples of polymerization processes that happen at a much faster pace, for example one monomer added to the mollecule every millisecond, or every few milliseconds.

The underlying question is: what is the fastest example of long-molecule elongation inside the cell? At physiologically viable concentrations, what is the fastest monomer addition process that we could find?

Comment: I have now found examples of polymerases approaching 1000 nucleotides per second. Is this correct? Any other examples? Specific polymerases that can reach this incorporation speed or even higher? Other polymerization examples?